# Unable to reset ProgressBar

Tags: c#, wpf

I am experimenting a behavior which makes me crazy.

I have a `ProgressBar` which represents the evolution of an import in database (in percents, from `0` to `100`).

After the import is done (`ProgressBar.Value = 100.0`), I open a log window with a code which looks like this :

```
RadWindow window = new RadWindow()
{
    //Set some properties
};
window.Closed += Log_Closed;
window.ShowDialog();
```

After the `RadWindow` is closed, I want to reset the `ProgressBar`. As you can see I use the function `Log_Closed` whose code is bellow :

```
private void Log_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //pbImport.Value = pbImport.Minimum; (didn't work)
    pbImport.Value = 0;
}
```

*Note* : `pbImport` is my progress bar.

**The instruction in** `Log_Closed` **has no effect.**

---

Before instruction :

[image: Before Instruction]

---

After instruction :

[image: After Instruction]

---

Obviously, the progress bar is not updated in UI. I can't understand this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the value of `pbImport.Minimum`?

Comment: The value of `pbImport.Minimum` is 0. This is defined in XAML and never changed. I also tried to set `pbImport.Value` to 1. The strange thing is that the update of my `ProgressBar` works during import.

Comment: Is ProgressBar.Value bound to a property of the viewmodel?

Comment: No. I update the `ProgressBar` manually with a `DoubleAnimation`.

Comment: You may also want to try modifying it wrapped inside a Dispatcher.Invoke call.

Comment: @RonBeyer Can you explicit your suggestion ?

Comment: If you are using animations, you have to remove the animation before you can edit the property, otherwise setting it has no effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Animations hold onto properties, in order to reset them in code, you have to remove the animation first so that the property is "released".

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for information on how to set a property after an animation in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the progress Bar can be achieved by using an "if" loop and incrementing the progress bar.

You can set a bool value for the database process and then simply:

```
private void Log_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //pbImport.Value = pbImport.Minimum; (didn't work)
    pbImport.Value = 0;

    if (database)
    {
        pbImport.Increment(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.animatable.beginanimation?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) -

> To remove a specific AnimationClock from a list of clocks, use the Controller property of the AnimationClock to retrieve a ClockController, then call the Remove method of the ClockController. This is typically done in the Completed event handler for a clock. Note that only root clocks can be controlled by a ClockController; the Controller property of a child clock will return null. Note also that the Completed event will not be called if the effective duration of the clock is forever. In that case, the user will need to determine when to call Remove.

In the example below I demonstrate setting up an event handler that runs when the animation is complete and removes the clock controller there, then set the ProgressBar value back to 0.

```
    void RunAnimation()
    {
        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new DoubleAnimation(100.0, duration);
        doubleanimation.Completed += ProgressBarCompleted;
        ProgBar.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleanimation);
    }

    private void ProgressBarCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var clock = (AnimationClock)sender;
        clock.Controller.Remove();
        ProgBar.Value = 0;
    }
```

Note: `ProgBar` is defined in a `.xaml` file like

```
<ProgressBar Margin="0,0,0,0"
             Padding="0,0,0,0"
             x:Name="ProgBar"
             Width="800"
             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
             Foreground="LightGray"/>
```